# Using keyword ASK for Google Assistant

Tags: actions-on-google

Is it possible to use the keyword "ask" with Actions-sdk? (not dialogflow)
Currently, I can start the process with "Talk to My App", which connects to my webservice. I then want to be able to say something like "ask John what room he is in"

What seems to happen is that Assistant (on Android) drops the "ask" and simply sends "John what room he is in" to the webhook api.

I guess that GA is listening for "ask" as an trigger word, but does that mean we cannot use it?  What other words might be impacted?  I've read lots of docs and don't see this clarified anywhere.

In case it is relevant, our service is trying to accept all spoken text for processing in our NLU, as the conversation paths are deep and complex, with many industry specific phrases and terms.

**EDIT**  Retested this again several days later and it is now sending the ASK keyword from a phone. Confused.
Not sure what SO practice is, delete question or keep it

Answer (score 0):

I just used the simulator to run a test using what I *think* is your test case:

I said "talk to 'my invocation name goes here' in the simulator. My Action was launched and its "main" aka "welcome" aka "default" intent was dispatched.

Then is said "ask 'invocation name' what time is it". The text intent was fired and the whole query beginning with ask which IME is not special-cased was returned.

Does that help?

Comment: Not quite what I need to do, I am trying to get 'ask XYZ' to be passed where XYZ is a random word not an invocation name,

Comment: It shouldn't matter. If you don't close the conversation in an SDK app, then subsequent utterances are in general routed to the "text intent". What I was trying to demonstrate is that "ask" is not special-cased when you are speaking within an open conversation with an Action. It is, however, special-cased when you are talking to the Google Assistant app when no conversation is ongoing.